# Execute a String as method in python

Tags: python

I currently have an object instance lets call it `myObject`. This `myObject` has methods like `executeX`, `executeY` etc. I want to pass this methods as strings such that I can do something like 
`command = data.get('do')` then `myObject.command` and have ***command*** be treated as an attribute. How can I achieve this??

Comment: You can't. `myObject.command` will access the attribute *named command*, the object also named command is uninvolved. If you want to access attributes from a string of their name, use `getattr`.

Comment: Thanks for this. @Aran-Fey